# Using XSL to display a hyperlink from XML on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to make a url in an XML file show up on an HTML page as a clickable hyperlink instead of just the url being displayed as text.

How can this be done? I'm pretty sure what I've done isn't far off...

Here's what the code looks like:

**XML**

```
<linkedin>
<discussion>
    <topic>This is the discussion name</topic>
    <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ligula mi, convallis eget iaculis id, euismod non arcu. Morbi porta.</content>
    <url>http://www.google.com</url>
</discussion>
</linkedin>
```

**XSL**

```
 <xsl:for-each select="linkedin/discussion">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="topic"/></h3>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="content"/></p>
    <p><a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="url"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="url"/></a></p>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

and I'm using JavaScript in the **HTML** to extract what's in the XML file

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","linkedin.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("discussion");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write("<p><strong>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("topic")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</strong></p><p>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</p><p>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
document.write("</p>");
</script>
```

Here's how it's looking... URL is just text and not a hyperlink:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the attached XSL anywhere? Do you need assistance with switching from your current solution to XSL, or just making your current solution work correctly?

Comment: @bububaba I would just like the current solution to work correctly. Can you see anything wrong in either the XML, XSL or HTML? Thanks

Comment: First of all I cannot locate where you are making use of the XSL that you pasted. Besides that, what you're missing is probably just the `<a>` tag with `href` attribute in your `document.write` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Made the JavaScript in my HTML this:

```
document.write("<p><strong>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("topic")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</strong></p><p>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</p><p>");
document.write("</p><p>");
document.write("<p><a href='");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
document.write("'>Click here to go through to the LinkedIn group</a></p>");
```